# angularfire2, how to bind to a list with a different path

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

Lets say I have:

```js
this.arrUserSchools = this.db.list('/users/' + this.userKey + '/schools');
```

and on my template:

```js
<li *ngFor="let school of arrUserSchools | async" >
  {{ school.name }}
</li>
```

so far it works great. However, if `this.userKey` changes, I need to define again `this.arrUserSchools = ...` and although it does work, I get the whole html blinking on every update of the list.

What is the proper way to set again `this.arrUserSchools` with the new path?

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole HTML"? The `li` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no problem in re-assigning the list bind:

```
this.arrUserSchools = this.db.list('/users/' + this.userKey + '/schools');
```

The problem was that I was subscribing multiple times somewhere else. (newbie mistake!) So the subscription was piling up with every run and therefore, reassigning multiple times the array containing the list to show on the template. That was making it "blink"

```
onFindUserByUid(uid: string) {

  this.findUserByUidSubscription = this.db.list('/users', {
    query: {
      orderByChild: 'uid',
      equalTo: uid
    }
  }).subscribe((snapshot) => {
    // do stuff ...
    this.findUserByUidSubscription.unsubscribe();  // <-- solution
  });

}
```